# Hyperlinked image positioned with CSS does not always work

Tags: html, css

The hyperlink on the first image does not work, on the second image it does. If I move the first image more to the right, only the right part of the image has a working hyperlink! Any help is appreciated!

I use the following styles:

```
.spc {position: absolute; top: 220px; }
.r   {position: relative; top: 1px; }
.k1  {position: relative; left: 1px; }
```

.k2  {position: relative; left: 129px; }

The images are positioned with:

```
<div class="spc"><div class="r"><div class="k1">
<a href="link.html"><img src="pic1"></a>
</div></div></div>
<div class="spc"><div class="r"><div class="k2">
<a href="link.html"><img src="pic2"></a>
</div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a href before div

```
<a href="link.html"><div class="spc"><div class="r"><div class="k1">
<img src="pic1"></a></a>
</div></div></div>
<a href="link.html"><div class="spc"><div class="r"><div class="k2">
<img src="pic2">
</div></div></div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your second div is overlapping the first div (coz u are taking as left:129px).

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mKZz7/) is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/mKZz7/